# Calling PDO->bindParam with a ternary conditional causes reference error

Tags: php, pdo, reference

I have a push to a database that creates a user account based on the information provided. Some information is required only based on other fields, such as:

$_POST['input3'] is only to be pushed to the database if $_POST['radio1'] is equal to 'other'. If not, push an empty string to the database (don't push the value of input3 regardless of its value).

My bindParam is as follows:

```
$user->bindParam(':input3', ($_POST['radio1'] == 'other')?$_POST['input3']:'');
```

Unfortunatly I get the following error: **Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference**.

In the past I'd take the conditional IF out of the function and simply have two different conditions where either the original value or an empty value would be binded, but I'm wondering if it's possible to put the conditional straight inside the function call.

Comment: Check `bindValue()` instead. Then read documentation on both

Comment: PS: what is the reason to bind an empty string?

Comment: String or NULL; just to have a standard 'empty' value across all fields in my database for when no data is saved.

Comment: if you don't care of its value - why to bind *anything*? Let database to use the column's default value

Comment: that's a... ...good point...

Comment: Well of course, you can't reference a string constant that isn't assigned to a variable anywhere (the third operand in the ternary is just that)

Comment: It was abit ignorant of me to place an empty string as the third operand in my conditional statement. I had tried a variable of empty value too, but that hadn't worked neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bindParam()` accepts a reference to a variable, so you cannot pass an expression.

If you want to use it that way (which I don't recommend, see comments) - then use `bindValue()` instead, which accepts expressions.

Comment: Why don't you recommend using it that way? I'm interested